# running spring mvc web app and jaxws soap web service in single tomcat instance having 1 web.xml file

Tags: spring, tomcat, soap, web-applications, jax-ws

I am making a zoho to quickbooks integration. In which I have created web application and soap service for quickbooks desktop to communicate with. My web app works fine with spring annotations but the autowired like annotations don't work. I want to know whether you can keep web.xml configuration like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>zohoquickbooks</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>2</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>zohoquickbooksdispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/zohoquickbooks-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>zohoquickbooksdispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
        com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener> 
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>qbservice</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>qbservice</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/qbservice</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  
  
 
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

This configuration works. One problem is there for jaxws service in web.xml. The object of implementation class is initiated by jax-ws container and not by spring so autowiring other objects in that class does not work. You can get spring managed objects into non spring managed object by doing specified in this URL "https://dzone.com/articles/autowiring-spring-beans-into-classes-not-managed-by-spring". Otherwise this configuration works fine. You can run web app and soap service on same container on same port. Just the url path needs to be different.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with spring boot without any xml.

You can use dependency: cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxws

It will separate your spring services from jaxws services. By default it will expose jaxws service at url: http://localhost:8080/services

Details you can read here https://cxf.apache.org/docs/springboot.html.

```
import org.apache.cxf.Bus;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

@Configuration
public class ApacheCxfConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Bus bus;

    @Bean
    public Endpoint endpoint() {
        EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(bus, new NumberConversionSoapTypeImpl());
        endpoint.publish("/hello");
        return endpoint;
    }
}



@WebService(name = "NumberConversionSoapType", targetNamespace = "http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface NumberConversionSoapType {

    /**
     * Returns the word corresponding to the positive number passed as parameter. Limited to quadrillions.
     * 
     * @param ubiNum
     * @return
     *     returns java.lang.String
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "NumberToWords")
    @WebResult(name = "NumberToWordsResult", targetNamespace = "http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "NumberToWords", targetNamespace = "http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/", className = "az.soap.NumberToWords")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "NumberToWordsResponse", targetNamespace = "http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/", className = "az.soap.NumberToWordsResponse")
    public String numberToWords(
        @WebParam(name = "ubiNum", targetNamespace = "http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/")
        BigInteger ubiNum);

}


@Service
@WebService(name = "NumberConversionSoapType", targetNamespace = "http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/")
public class NumberConversionSoapTypeImpl implements NumberConversionSoapType {
    @Override
    public String numberToWords(BigInteger ubiNum) {
        System.out.println("numberToWords");
        return null;
    }
}
```